# GridView Binding Shows The parameter is incorrect

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 (WINRT). I have a GridView to show photos from server.

**XAML is:**

```
 <Grid x:Name="PhotosGrid" >
    <GridView 
     x:Name="PhotosGridView"
     ItemsSource="{Binding}"
     ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True"
     IsItemClickEnabled="True"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PhotosItemTemplate}">       
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>
</Grid>


<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PhotosItemTemplate">
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=photo}"                       
                           ImageFailed="Photo_ImageFailed"
                     >
                     </Image>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

**Class is:**

```
 public class Photo
    {
        public string photo { get; set; }
    }
```

**C#:**

```
ObservableCollection<Photo> PhotosList = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
int i = 0;
foreach(var photos in MyProfileResultObject.Photos )
    {
    PhotosList.Add(new Photo { photo = MyProfileResultObject.Photos[i].photo});
    i++;
    }                                    
PhotosGridView.ItemsSource = PhotosList;
```

**But I am getting error:**

> {System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect.
>
> The parameter is incorrect. }
>
> ```
>         UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
>         {
>             if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
>         };
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=photo}"
        ImageFailed="Photo_ImageFailed" >
        </Image>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```